# How to match the no of responses returned with a value displayed in the response body

Tags: json, api, postman

I have the below response in my postman Body .

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "c2004ef952894279920417ba8283d26a",
            "name": "attrib_inv_bu",
            "modified_date": "2020-07-06T02:15:06.839577",
            "display_group": {
                "id": "attr_dis_267a405426184764816e504b4f0a565b",
                "name": "Custom"
            },
            "api_url": "https://abc.xyz.com/api/v1/attributes/attr_c2004ef952894279920417ba8283d26a/",
            "url": "https://abc.xyz.com/manage/matter_attributes/2707/"
        },
        
        {
            "id": "c2004ef95289422324232a8283d26a",
            "name": "attrib_idsdw_sfs",
            "modified_date": "2020-07-06T02:11:06.839577",
            "display_group": {
                "id": "attr_dis_267a4054261dfsf64816e504b4f0a565b",
                "name": "Custom"
            },
            "api_url": "https://abc.xyz.com/api/v1/attributes/attr_c2004ef952894279920417ba8ssd3d26a/",
            "url": "https://abc.xyz.com/manage/matter_attributes/2709/"
        },
        {
            "id": "c2004ef9we22e2e8283d26a",
            "name": "attrib_iasa_ac",
            "modified_date": "2020-07-06T02:17:06.839577",
            "display_group": {
                "id": "attr_dis_267a405426184764816e5dsds4f0a565b",
                "name": "Custom"
            },
            "api_url": "https://abc.xyz.com/api/v1/attributes/attr_c2004ef952894279920417ba8283sds26a/",
            "url": "https://abc.xyz.com/manage/matter_attributes/2708/"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to assert whether I have 3 different ids match with the count 3 that is displayed in the body.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = pm.response.json()
res.count === res.results.length
```

you can use in expect as :

```
pm.expect(res.count).to.be.equal(res.results.length)
```

If you want to verify they are indeed unique:

```
let resultidlits = []

result.forEach((a) => {

resultidlits.includes(a.id)? null : resultidlits.push(a.id)


})

 pm.expect(res.count).to.be.equal(resultidlits.length)
```